# how can i retrieve the text data from sqlite datadase in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am using this

```
  -(void) Data

  {
   databaseName = @"List.sqlite";

  NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     
      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
  databasePath =[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

  [self checkAndCreateDatabase];


  sqlite3 *database;
  if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
  {
    if(detailStmt == nil)
    {
        const char *sql = "Select item from list";          
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &detailStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {               
            NSLog(@"Hiiiiiii");

            while(sqlite3_step(detailStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                NSLog(@"Helllloooooo");
                NSString *item= [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 0)];

                //item1=item;
                NSLog(@"%@",item);


            }
            sqlite3_reset(detailStmt);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(detailStmt);
        sqlite3_clear_bindings(detailStmt);
    }
}
detailStmt = nil;
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: @uttam: Please provide more specific details about what you want.

Comment: Why not just use Core Data?  The sqlite API is actually quite thoroughly difficult to use correctly. Core Data has better introductory documentation and better support.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look [at this tutorial.](http://bit.ly/sqliteForIPhone) It always helped me when I used `sqlite` in `ios`. For me it looks like you should structure your code a little bit, you shouldn't load any path's inside a query method.

Maybe the problem occurs because of

```
sqlite3_reset(detailStmt);
sqlite3_clear_bindings(detailStmt);
```